# NavigationStack and toolbar incompatibility

Tags: swiftui

I have the following view setup. A content view with `TextField` in the toolbar position `.principal` (so, inside the NavigationBar in iOS) and a button that toggles focus on the `TextField`. As well as an enclosing view handling some navigation.

```swift
struct FocusStateView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var username = "Anonymous"

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button("Toggle Focus") {
                    isFocused.toggle()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("Enter your username", text: $username)
                        .focused($isFocused)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct NavigationWrapper: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            FocusStateView()
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
                    ContentView()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This setup doesn't work unless either the `.navigationDestination` modifier is moved inside of `FocusStateView` or the `TextField` is moved from the toolbar into the `VStack`.

So the following would be working:

```swift
struct FocusStateView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var username = "Anonymous"

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button("Toggle Focus") {
                    isFocused.toggle()
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("Enter your username", text: $username)
                        .focused($isFocused)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
                ContentView()
            }
    }
}

struct NavigationWrapper: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            FocusStateView()
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like a bug to me, but please let me know if I'm handling something in the wrong way.

Essentially I would like to keep all the navigation-related logic in `NavigationWrapper` if possible.

Also posted to [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728729)